# How to trigger a service to start at a certain date and time?

Tags: java, android, service, android-jobscheduler

This is my activity class:

```
 public class activity extends AppCompatActivity{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

Intent i = new Intent(activity.this, Service.class);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                      Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                      c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,mHour);
                      c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,mMinute);
                      c.set(year,month,date);
                      c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startService(i);
                    }
                    }
```

And this is my service class:

```
public class Smscreator extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Context context=getApplicationContext();

    Toast.makeText(context, "This is the service.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

}
```

This is my Manifest class:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <application
                <service
                android:name=".Service"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"></service>
                <activity android:name=".activity" 
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>

            </manifest>
```

The variables `mHour`,`mMinute`,`year`,`month` and `date` are certain values for the date and time that depends on the user.

Now when I execute this code, the service gets triggered instantly; it completely ignores the date and time specified by the user. Can someone please help me with this?

**Edit:** I am currently working on Android M.

Comment: `c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` sets the calendar to the current time and date, previous settings are overwritten. Moreover you call `startService()` after that directly.

Comment: I've tried removing c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); but still the service gets triggered instantly.

Comment: I have added more to my comment.

Comment: If I don't add the startService(i); then the service never gets triggered.

Comment: Next problem is that your intent doesn't start your `Smscreator` service but tries to start something represented by the generic `Service` class which won't work. Maybe you should work through the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/) and the provided tutorials before doing something more involved.

Comment: Ok I see now, I have to use the jobscheduler to start the service, but I don't know anything about it. Can you please guide me on how to work with it? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: This is too broad for a question here. For a start you can look at [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129).